# getimagesize in php returning false

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

I am trying to make a web service and in that service, I need people to upload images, but when I try uploading images with the following code, getimagesize returns false. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<form action="../askcheck.php" method="post" id="ask" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div><input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" accept="image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/JPG,image/JPEG,image/png,image/PNG" /></div>
    <div><button type="submit">submit</button></div>
```

PHP:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"])){
    $check=getimagesize($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check==false){
        //check if the uploaded file is an image    
        $uploadok=0;
        echo 'not an image';
    }
}
```

When I upload a image, it echos 'not an image'. What am I doing wrong? I have tried multiple images.

Edited notes:

When I echo the GD Version of my server, it gives me 'bundled (2.1.0 compatible)'

Second Edited notes:
The problem is solved, but not in a professional way. I contacted my host about this, and the host did something and told me to try it again, and then it worked. I have no idea what he did, but it must have had to do with some kind of server settings.

Comment: have you verified that you have the GD extension?

Comment: also, use `===` because `==` doesn't check if it's actually false, it just checks if it's *falsy*

Comment: Your code as posted is working. Can you include a sample image or link to one that fails your test? Also note that `getimagesize` does not require the GD image library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get file size directly using `$_FILES['photo']['size']` or if it is image size like length and width of image you may have to check if GD package is loaded properly

Comment: getimagesize does a lot more than get the image's size. it returns mimetype, etc as well.